# Can you run require_once recursively in php?

Tags: php, require-once

Is it possible to run `require_once` recursively in one line like this:

```
<?php
require_once('./OAuth2/*');
```

Or would you have to go to each file directly and `require` it?

Comment: You're better off using an autoloader

Comment: You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) to get a list of the files that match that pattern in an array, `foreach` over the array and include each element. But you should probably consider using an [autoloader](http://php.net/spl-autoload-register) instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cant do it that way. something like this would work:

```
foreach (glob("./OAuth2/*.php") as $filename)
{
    require_once($filename);
}
```

Comment: +1 I use this all the time and it works great. I typically do it this way though 

`foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename) {
 require_once($filename);
}`

with the .php there to ensure I dont include any other random files that may be in the directory (maybe like an index.html file)

Answer (score 0):

recursively all file list and require_once in one directory:

```
$files = array();

function require_once_dir($dir){

       global $files;

       $item = glob($dir);

       foreach ($item as $filename) {

             if(is_dir($filename)) {

                  require_once_dir($filename.'/'. "*");

             }elseif(is_file($filename)){

                  $files[] = $filename;
             }
        }
}

$recursive_path = "path/to/dir";

require_once_dir($recursive_path. "/*");

for($f = 0; $f < count($files); $f++){

     $file = $files[$f];

     require_once($file);
}
```